# A function to get the smaller number

Tags: php, minimum

I have 2 variables each containing a number (integer). I would like to sort them to have the lowest number first and the second largest. For example:

```
$sortedVar = getSmaller(45, 62); // Will return 45
$sortedVar = getSmaller(87, 23); // Will return 23
```

Do you see what I want to do? Can you help me please?
Thanks :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.min.php

> min — Find lowest value..
>
> If the first and only parameter is an array, `min()` returns the lowest value in that array. If at least two parameters are provided, `min()` returns the smallest of these values.
>
> > **Note:**
> >     Values of different types will be compared using the [standard comparison rules](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php). For instance, a non-numeric [string](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) will be compared to an [integer](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php) as though it were 0, but multiple non-numeric [string](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) values will be compared alphanumerically. The actual value returned will be of the original type with no conversion applied.
> >
> > **Caution**
> >     Be careful when passing arguments with mixed types values because `min()` can produce unpredictable results...

Comment: That would work with arrays, but he's got just plain variables here.

Comment: @Tatu - actually `min` can take as many arguments as you pass it or an array.

Comment: @Jenson: it's a good idea to accept the answer that solves your problem.

Answer (score 8):

Use [min()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.min.php) which supports any number of arguments as well as arrays.

```
$smallest = min(1,2); //returns 1
$smallest = min(4,3,2); //returns 2
$smallest = min(array(5,4)) //returns 4
```

Answer (score 5):

```
function getSmaller($a, $b) {
    return $a < $b ? $a : $b;
}
```

In plain english, if $a is smaller than $b, then return $a, else return $b.

Or as others pointed out, there's also a function for that, called [min()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.min.php).

Answer (score 2):

```
$sortedVar = $a < $b ? $a : $b;
```